# Angular-UI tooltips on d3.js svg elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js, angular-ui

Hey I´m trying to use Angular UI tooltips on d3.js SVG elements. I´m generating the elements in a controller.

```
 context.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("svg:circle")
  .attr("tooltip-append-to-body", true)
  .attr("tooltip", function(d){
             return d.name;
         })
```

The elements and tooltip attributes in the code are shown correctly, but no tooltips appear.
When I add tooltips in HTML it is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike html where tooltips are attributes, in SVG tooltips are child elements i.e. you need to construct something like

```
<circle>
   <title>tooltip</title>
</circle>
```

via

```
.append("svg:title")
```

Comment: Thanks! The tooltip works great, but is there any chance styling the native tooltips?

Comment: Not from within the page content. You'd need to modify the browser's own configuration files.